# Better way to perform NLP sentence topic classification?

Tags: python, nlp, classification, huggingface-transformers, text-classification

For one of my projects I have been classifying sentences according to predefined topics/labels.
This sentences are provided through long texts with different paragraphs.

**Current Status**
For this task I have perform as follows

1. Training:

- I label thousands of sentences related with the task
- I balance the training dataset
- I finetuned Bert (tried deberta but for me is not performing better and seems to be slower)

2. Use:

- I segment the text into sentences
- I apply the NLP finetuned model (Bert)

**Question**

The accuracy is good, but since I segment the text, some times there are sentences that have no topic out of the full context. Nevertheless, if you read the text you know that they are talking about topic X. After doing some research I couldn't come with a direct solution, therefore my question would be:

- There is some better way to do?
  For example, can I train some model that reads the full text and then provides me the topic for each part of the text (as a mask for example). Then I can take the parts that talk about each topic and separate them in sentences.
- Would this incur a decrease in the general performance of the topic labelling?

Thank you very much for your time and support.

Comment: Based on my understanding, did you try to split the text based on delimiters, and predict on individual text? or  do you want NER type prediction?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! 

As a first approach, I split the text with an NLP pipeline that first punctuates the text and then splits using both delimiters and "sentence meaning". 

The issue is that some times, the sentence split has not a direct topic related (e.g. "This feels so comfortable"). But when you read the full paragraph you see that they are talking about an specific topic (e.g. "Sofas")

Due to this my thought was: Can some mix between this and NER be created, that detects the topic connecting the different parts of the text?

Comment: My two cents for this question, I have done little similar to this. i.e predicting multi-label classification using model which trained single label. what I have done I created n-grams based on length of text, and make prediction multiple times. as I  have used TF Universal sentence encoders, prediction on multiple time will not take much time. NER I did not personally done. you can give a try for custom NER and mix